# Hex code color library for Android Studio

Tags: android, colors

I'm developing an Android application named color scan for color blindness.
The function of scan is already done in my project.
The only problem is, I need a color library to support my project.
I'm using mysqlite database for my application and I add the color code and name to the database,
but the problem is that there are too many codes there
so I need a color library.

The picture below is about sample coding add color code and name to database.
[image: sample coding add color code and name to database]

It's not enough to my project.

Please help.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to make db table for color value
You can create the colors.xml file in the res/values folder of your project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
 <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
 <color name="fuchsia">#FF00FF</color>
 <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
 <color name="silver">#C0C0C0</color>
 <color name="gray">#808080</color>
 <color name="olive">#808000</color>
 <color name="purple">#800080</color>
 <color name="maroon">#800000</color>
 <color name="aqua">#00FFFF</color>
 <color name="lime">#00FF00</color>
 <color name="teal">#008080</color>
 <color name="green">#008000</color>
 <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
 <color name="navy">#000080</color>
 <color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: hi
because i make the function flow as below:
scan color => get color code=> compare with db color => output color name
if i use your way to create the colors.xml file, i still need create one by one (coding)
so im asking have any faster way there ?
thankyou so much

Comment: I means the barcode scanner application will use the ZXing Scanner library
so do any color library i can use ?
ps: already searching from google there is no any library of color code and name